# NodeJS Express app generation with CoffeeScript and HAML

Tags: node.js, express, coffeescript, haml

I just started looking into NodeJS and Express and found out about the possibility to generate a new app that uses hogan right from the start:

```
express <appname> -c [stylus, less] --hogan --ejs
```

Is there a way to generate a new app that uses CoffeeScript, HAML instead of Jade and Less/SCSS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a generator, but you can easily make an express app using HAML and coffeescript.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "haml-coffee-express",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "",
    "express-partials": "",
    "haml-coffee": "",
    "coffee-script": ""
  }
}
```

**server.coffee:**

```
express = require("express")
partials = require("express-partials")
app = express()
app.engine "hamlc", require("haml-coffee").__express 
app.use partials()

app.set "view engine", "hamlc"

app.get "/", (req, res) ->
  res.render "index",
  name: "User"

app.listen 3000
console.log "App started on port 3000"
```

**views/layout.hamlc:**

```
!!!
%head
  %title Express App
%body
  != @body
```

**views/index.hamlc:**

```
%h1= "Welcome #{ @name }"
%p You've rendered your first Haml Coffee view.
```

Afterwards, just run this command and you are good to go.

> npm install && node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee server.coffee