# How do I get HAML layouts working with haml-coffee and Express 4?

Tags: node.js, ruby, express, haml

I followed "[NodeJS Express app generation with CoffeeScript and HAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22116481/nodejs-express-app-generation-with-coffeescript-and-haml/22117941#22117941)" and the [express-usage docs](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee#express-usage), but my layout is not displaying.

I can see the rendered `index.hamlc` OK, but it doesn't contain the layout. How do I get layout to work with HAML and Express 4?

server.js:

```
const express = require('express'),
    partials = require("express-partials"),
...
app.set('views','app/views');
app.engine("hamlc", require("haml-coffee").__express)
app.use(partials())
app.set("view engine", "hamlc")
```

index.js:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', {name: "User"})
```

app/views/layout.hamlc:

```
!!!
%head
  %title Express App
%body
  xxx
  != @body
```

I viewed the source in Chrome using `view-source:http://127.0.0.1/` and it only shows the template contents but not the layout.

Comment: Be careful using a browser to view source. They're like little puppies and want to help and will mangle the source trying to display something to you. `wget` or `curl` or a gem like HTTParty can show you what is really there and won't get in your way.

Comment: True but not even the `<html>` or `<head>` tags were there.

Comment: Ah, but we can't tell that because we have no example HTML to review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the line

```
app.use('/', indexRouter)
```

below

```
app.engine("haml", require("haml-coffee").__express)
app.use(partials())
app.set("view engine", "haml")
```

and it worked. I didn't think the order would matter.  (I also renamed the files `.haml` to match conventions and enable syntax hilighting.)